# Are real numbers complex conjugates of one another?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers

I'm just stuck with a technical part of my proof that might just be a triviality:  if two different numbers are both real, are they complex conjugates of each other?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried computing what the complex conjugate of a real number is??

Comment: Of course not. A real number is its own complex conjugate.

Comment: @rschwieb yes, I have - it's just its real part.  I knew that but for some strange reason I thought of something else ...

Comment: the complex conjugate of a real number is itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - the complex conjugate of any given real number $a$ is itself:
$$a=a+0i=a-0i=\overline{a}$$
Thus, if you have two **different** real numbers, they are not complex conjugates of each other.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

This is obvious in the sense that if $z=x+iy$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}$, then $y=0$. Similarly, $\bar{z}=x-iy=x.$ I assume that you are referring to the *same* complex number.